# add metadata to liquid templates using jekyll plugin

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I am new to Jekyll. I have a post with the following yml front matter:

```
---
layout: images-grid
title: Grid Sample
image: "/imgs/image1.jpg"
---
```

I would like to create .rb plugin that identifies all the posts with "layout = images-grid" and adds the height and the width of the image as a yaml metadata so the height and the width will be available to the liquid templates.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

could you not do something like this in your file?

```
{% if page.layout == images-grid %}
// do something
<img src="{{image}}" class="image-class"/>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for something similar (well not really *similar*, but the goal is the same, use a plugin to edit the front-matter of a post or posts).

So far the only option that I've found is to actually use the ruby File class to open and edit the file. So something like:

```
fileHandler = File.open("2013-11-23-post-title.html", "w+")
```

and then read in lines, editing/adding your new content to the front matter as necessary, i.e.:

```
fileHandler.puts "height: 480px\n width: 640px"
```

It would be nicer/ideal if the front-matter was available for manipulation as an attribute of the page or post object, but I don't think it is. I'm going to check the project page on github to see if there is already a feature request open for that.